Oauth2 google authorisation server to access spring boot api and check user localy
I have a android application that connects to a rest API developed with spring boot.
The user login to his google account on the phone get a jwt token (openid) from the google authorisation server. Then, this token is sent to the API to authenticate the user.
Is it correct that the ressource server can trust the mail adress in the passed jwt token?
This works well with this spring security snipet of code:
public class SecurityConfigurationO2Auth {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfigurationO2Auth.class);

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwt-set-uri}")
    private String jwkSetUri;

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        JwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
        return new JwtDecoder() {
            @Override
            public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {
                logger.info(token);
                Jwt jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(token);
                logger.info("Access requested for : " + jwt.getClaimAsString("email"));
                logger.info("that expires at : " + jwt.getClaimAsString("exp"));
                return jwt;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
                .decoder(jwtDecoder()).and().and().cors().and().csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}

With this solution anyone with a google account can access my rest API.
I have no mean to configure the google authorisation server to restrict the access to a set of predifined mail adresses.
So, I would like to be able to check the existance of the mail address in the local database. If not present, reply with a 401 not authorized.
Would you have a hint how to customize this in the security filter chain? Add a filter, customise the oauth2ResourceServer?
I would like to take the best approach with spring security


Is it correct that the ressource server can trust the mail adress in the passed jwt token?

Yes, provided that the email_verified claim value is true.
But:

what you currently exchange between your mobile application and your Spring backend probably is ID tokens (not access tokens). ID tokens audience is OAuth2 Clients, and it shouldn't be used for access control on resource servers
access tokens issued by Google most likely have Google API as audience - not your resource servers. Also, these tokens are most likely opaque - not JWTs. For these reasons, you should not use them for authorizing requests to your resource servers.

What you should do is use an OpenID Provider of your own, with Google as an identity provider (one with "Login with Google" feature). Something like Keycloak if you want it to run on your servers, or a cloud offering like Auth0, Amazon Cognito, or whatever your provider offers. You could also have a look at Spring Authorization Server, but it requires much more work and probably a better knowledge of OAuth2 and OpenID than you have.
Your applications would use this new authorization server which will proxy identities issued by Google (and the emails the ID tokens contain), and issue JWT access tokens with your resource servers as audience. This authorization server will also serve as a "user service" for your backend: about all solutions offer a REST API to access and update user data like roles (at least, those I listed do).
Also, you should probably have a look at the OAuth2 BFF pattern to use "confidential" clients instead of "public" ones and hide tokens from the mobile application: tokens are easier to steal if they are issued to clients without a secret, transit on the Internet, are manipulated by the application code (and by its dependencies, some of which could be compromised), and are stored on the mobile device. So it's much safer if tokens do not leave the backend.

My suggestion is to keep the User Authentication/Authorization logic in a filter configured at API Gateway level.
If the user is valid or passed the authentication/authorization then only we will route the request to the actual REST API being invoked.
